# Android Graph View auto scrollable Line Graph

Tags: android, android-studio, viewport, android-graphview, linegraph

I have created a `line graph` using `Grap View` and I am able to scroll it manually right and left but I am unable to set it to `scroll automatically`. So far I haven't found any thread in which someone would try this so I am wondering if `Graph View` even supports auto scroll.

This is my code so far:

```
    graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph);

    // first series is a line
    DataPoint[] points = new DataPoint[1000];
    for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        points[i] = new DataPoint(i, Math.sin(i*0.5) * 20*(Math.random()*10+1));
    }
    series = new LineGraphSeries<>(points);

    // set manual X bounds
    graph.getViewport().setYAxisBoundsManual(true);
    graph.getViewport().setMinY(-150);
    graph.getViewport().setMaxY(200);

    graph.getViewport().setXAxisBoundsManual(true);

    Handler handler1 = new Handler();
    for (orderNr = 1; orderNr < 50 ;orderNr++) {
        handler1.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                graph.getViewport().setMinX(orderNr);
                graph.getViewport().setMaxX(orderNr + 100);
                graph.addSeries(series);

            }
        }, 1000);
    }
    graph.getViewport().setScrollable(true); // enables horizontal scrolling
```

If i do not do it within a `Thread` the lines

`graph.getViewport().setMinX(orderNr)` and 
`graph.getViewport().setMaxX(orderNr + 100)`

set the graph to start and end at the specified spot but when they are put in a `Thread` I think that the `Thread` first finishes, reaching max `orderNr` and then draws out the `graph`.

Maybe someone has tried this with `MPAndroidChart` or `aChartEngine` or something else and can tell me what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem also happened to me, but I got around it by setting isScalable to true and scroll to end at every update. This code results in a graphView that has a scrolling width of 30 and y limits at 0 and 1000.

```
class ScrollingGraphView(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet): GraphView(context, attrs) {
    private var series = LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>();
    private var x = 0.0

    init {
        addSeries(series)
        viewport.isScrollable = true
        viewport.isScalable = true
        viewport.isYAxisBoundsManual = true
        viewport.setMinY(0.0)
        viewport.setMaxY(1000.0)
        viewport.setMinX(0.0)
        viewport.setMaxX(30.0)
    }

    fun addEntry(y:Double?) {
        if(null != y) {
            x += .1
            series.appendData(DataPoint(x, y), true, 200)
        }
        invalidate()
        viewport.scrollToEnd()
    }
```